# How to use a Fastify application with a plain Node.js HTTP server?

Tags: node.js, fastify

I want to use Fastify to create a REST API, but I want to use it with a plain Node.js `http.Server` instance created and configured by myself, and *not* use `fastify.listen()` for creating the socket.

With express.js, you can just pass the application handler to `http.createServer()` like this:

```
import http from "node:http";
import express from "express";
const expressApp = express();

// creating routes here

const httpServer = http.createServer(expressApp);
httpServer.listen({
  port: 80,
  host: "127.0.0.1",
});
```

I have tried that with an object created via `fastify()` but it does not work. Is there another way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the [`serverFactory`](https://github.com/fastify/fastify/blob/main/docs/Reference/Server.md#serverfactory) option

```
const http = require('http')

let server

const serverFactory = (handler, opts) => {
  server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    handler(req, res)
  })

  return server
}

const fastify = require('fastify')({ serverFactory })

fastify.get('/', (req, reply) => {
  reply.send({ hello: 'world' })
})

fastify.ready(() => {
  server.listen({ port: 8080 })
})
```

> and not use fastify.listen() for creating the socket.

You need to call `fastify.ready()` in any case, or the plugins will not be loaded.